# Realm.io with AnyObject subscript

Tags: swift, realm

I'm about to implement Realm models in my Swift 2.0 app. However, once I pod install Realm. My AnyObject subscripts for my app will cause a compile error

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject' with an index of type 'String'
>
> Cannot subscript a value of type 'RLMProperty'  with an index of type 'String'
>
> Conditional cast from 'RLMProperty' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds

But the thing is outlet is not supposed to be a RLMProperty in the first place

The following is my code

```
var campaigns = [AnyObject]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let campaignCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("campaignCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CampaignTableViewCell
    
    let outlet: AnyObject = (self.campaigns[indexPath.section]["surveys"]!![indexPath.row])["outlet"]!!
    
    
    // Configure the cell...
    campaignCell.outletID.text = outlet["code"] as? String
    campaignCell.outletNameLabel.text = outlet["name"] as? String
    //campaignCell.outletAddressLabel.text = outlet["outlet"]!!["address"] as? String
    campaignCell.outletStatusLabel.text = (self.campaigns[indexPath.section]["surveys"]!![indexPath.row])["progress"]!!["name"] as? String
    
    campaignCell.outletStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(((self.campaigns[indexPath.section]["surveys"]!![indexPath.row])["progress"]!!["color"] as? String)!)
    
    return campaignCell
}
```

Comment: This question was raised also as a [Github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2623) in the Realm-Cocoa repo.

Comment: Can you provide any more information about this issue? Which lines are associated with those errors?

Comment: I'm also seeing this same error in a project. It emerged as soon as I imported RealmSwift in one of the project's files. It happens without any references to Realm other than the import statement.

Comment: @Happiehappie: Can you please address the questions, I asked on the GitHub issue?

Comment: @angelo: Another question would be just, which other 3rd party frameworks, do you import beside Realm?

Comment: The reason I assosiate this with Realm is because, it worked fine until I import Realm in my pod, I've tested this by removing realm and things worked fine again

Comment: @Happiehappie: Could you resolve this issue meanwhile? Otherwise I'd really need to know what you use alongside, even though the issue might disappear through removing Realm, I can't find the cause without that knowledge. We test all integration scenarios and never came across such an error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error myself - the trick was simply not to use `AnyObject` when you wish to access properties via a subscript.

Chances are, your instance(s) of `AnyObject` is already a dictionary of some form.  If you know your keys are all strings, simply cast your object to `[String: AnyObject]` - otherwise, use `[NSObject: AnyObject]`.  There is also a lot of force unwrapping going on in your sample, which I'm afraid is just asking for crashes!  So how would I re-write your sample?

```
if let campaign = self.campaigns[indexPath.section] as? [String: AnyObject],
    surveys = campaign["surveys"] as? [AnyObject],
    survey = surveys[indexPath.row] as? [String: AnyObject],
    outlet = survey["outlet"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

    // Set up your cell here

}
```

Long story short, `if-let` is your friend!  Nil checking and type casting in one!

Better still, map your dictionaries to classes/structs and enjoy the benefits of strong typing - there are plenty of third party Swift frameworks to make this much easier!